# Cocos2d:App crashing after closing mail composer view

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my app i am having 7 button i am show 3 button in that view after pressing  down arrow it show other 3 button

1.Facebook share
2.twitter share
3.tell a friend
4.report
5.starter guide
6.visit my  web site
7. feed back

```
     LIKE THIS MY VIEW
    ====================
          ^        ---->up arrow

      facebook share

      Twitter share

      Tell a friend

           V      ---->down arrow
```

i am using mailcomposerview for "tell a friend" button and "report" button

when i press "Tell a Friend" or "report" button it opens mailcomposerview  after closing that i am not able to move the up and down arrow......if i press the up and down arrow it open the same mail composerview,its   also not opening facebook share and twitter share

please help me to fix this issue

### my coding when arrow pressed

```
 -(void)arrTapped1:(id)sender
 {
CCMenuItem *item2=(CCMenuItem*)sender;
int k=item2.tag;
    ////CCLOG(@"k tapp=%dhelp=%d",k,helpVal);

    NSLog(@"HelpVal%i",helpVal);
if(k==51)
{
    if(helpVal<3)
    { 
        id action1=[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.3 position:ccp(0,+260)];
        id callfun1=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(enabled1) ]; 

        [item2 setIsEnabled:YES];
        [(CCSprite*)[self getChildByTag:10] runAction:[CCSequence actions:action1,callfun1,nil]];
        [self performSelector:@selector(downWardsMove)];
            }

}
else //if(k==50)
        {
    if(helpVal>1)
    {  

        id action1=[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.3 position:ccp(0,-260)];
        id callfun1=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(enabled1) ]; 
        [item2 setIsEnabled:YES];

        [(CCSprite*)[self getChildByTag:10] runAction:[CCSequence actions:action1,callfun1,nil]];
        [self performSelector:@selector(upWardsMove)];
    }   } }

    //code for upwards & downwards move
    //--------------------------------

  -(void)upWardsMove
   {
      [upArrItem setIsEnabled:NO];
  [downArrItem setIsEnabled:NO];
  self.isTouchEnabled=NO;
  helpVal--;
  [(CCMenu*)[self getChildByTag:53] setVisible:YES];
  [downArrItem setIsEnabled:YES];
      if(helpVal==1)
  {
    [(CCMenu*)[self getChildByTag:52] setVisible:NO];
    [upArrItem setIsEnabled:NO];
  } 
   }


-(void)downWardsMove
 {
    [upArrItem setIsEnabled:NO];
[downArrItem setIsEnabled:NO];
self.isTouchEnabled=NO;
    helpVal++;
    [(CCMenu*)[self getChildByTag:52] setVisible:YES];
[upArrItem setIsEnabled:YES];
if(helpVal==3){
    [(CCMenu*)[self getChildByTag:53] setVisible:NO];
    [downArrItem setIsEnabled:NO];
}
}
 -(void)enabled1
  {
self.isTouchEnabled=YES;
[upArrItem setIsEnabled:YES];
[downArrItem setIsEnabled:YES];
if(helpVal==3)
{
    [(CCMenu*)[self getChildByTag:53] setVisible:NO];
    [downArrItem setIsEnabled:NO];
}
if(helpVal==1)
{
    [(CCMenu*)[self getChildByTag:52] setVisible:NO];
    [upArrItem setIsEnabled:NO];
}
   }

 //sending mail code
//------------------

-(void)sendMail
{
  mailComposer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:mailComposer.view];
  MFMailComposeViewController *mailController= [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];                
  mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;    
  [mailController setSubject:msgSubject];
  [mailController setMessageBody:mailContent isHTML:YES];
  NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Info@ask.com"];
  [mailController setBccRecipients:toRecipients];
  [mailComposer presentModalViewController:mailController animated:NO];
  mailComposer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f ) );
  [mailController release];
  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight]     
  }

 -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)mailController didFinishWithResult: (MFMailComposeResult)result  error:(NSError*)error
 {
    [mailComposer dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: Does didFinishWithResult delegate method get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a part of a code that I used in my apps and it works well in iOS 4.0 - iOS 6.0. Take a look:

```
-(void)sendMessageToEmail:(NSString *)message withSubject:(NSString *)subject
{
    if([self _isIOS6andHigher]) {

        NSArray *activities = @[message];
        UIActivityViewController *viewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activities applicationActivities:nil];

        AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[app navController] presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        [viewController release];

    } else {

        MFMailComposeViewController* mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailController setSubject:subject];
        [mailController setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];

        AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [[app navController] presentModalViewController:mailController animated:YES];
        [mailController release];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                    error:(NSError*)error
{
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: what does the AppController mean. where should i declare and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You never release mailComposer:

```
mailComposer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

This might cause it to leak and remain active as a view. That could explain the lack of touch events because mail composer might still intercept touches.

Comment: after release the mailcomposer i getting the same problem